# Inkscape bizzare copy and paste behaviour

Tags: inkscape, text

I've got a PDF document I've imported into Inkscape as a raster image with poppler/cairo import. The document has text and mathematical equations and I want to copy parts of it into a another Inkscape document. When I try to select some text and copy it into it, it seemingly changes font, size and adds lots of spaces between the letters.

This:

[image]

Turns into this [image]

How do I copy this without it changing? If I import internal import or the vector alternative, the text and mathethematics loses it's formatting/font which I want it to retain.

Comment: You can't edit or copy text in Inkscape which has been rasterized.  Inkscape is a vector image editor, not a raster image editor.  Also rasters don't contain editable text anyway - they are just images made of pixels.  You might have more luck using something like Scribus to edit a PDF. Try that. Obviously, there may still be font or formatting issues, so I can't promise it will work.

Comment: I know, I don't want to edit anything, I just want the image of the text. I'm making a collage :) If I import it as a vector image, I lose all the formatting and font of the text, which I would like to keep for artistic purposes.

Comment: Do you have access to the original source file? If so, it might be better to convert all objects including text to outlines.